# Collecting photodiode current in specific capacitor

Tags: capacitor, adc, photodiode

I want to be able to measure the amount of light that hits a photodiode during different timeslices specified by particular signals.  For example, below when S1 is high I want C1 to charge, and when S2 is high I want C2 to charge.  After a particular period, I want to be able to measure the amounts in C1 and C2 by measuring the voltages at the points indicated by ADC1 and ADC2.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8Qjih.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've gotten it to work in a rudimentary way, although I have the following issues:

- I haven't worked out how to reset the capacitors
- The capacitors seem to charge themselves from the ADC pin.  How do I prevent this?

If it makes a difference, I am using a Raspberry Pi Pico to measure the voltages.

Comment: https://www.thinksrs.com/products/boxcar.html

Answer (score 3):

Buffer the ADC inputs with op-amps that have very low input bias currents.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.  To be honest I don't know anything about op-amps.  Can you suggest a comprehensive source?  Maybe a book where I can learn it properly?

Comment: @CaptainCodeman The [wikipedia article on opamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier) and [their applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier_applications) is not too bad a place to start

Comment: In this case all you should need is the op-amp votlage follower or buffer circuit, and then search for op-amps that accommodate your input range, output range, and low input bias currents. 1-10pA is common for the low range. Below that requires more exotic op-amps. You may want to check your RPI datasheet for the currents on the ADC pins so you have something to aim below.

Comment: Can you tell me please, what is the function of the op-amp for this application?  I don't want to amplify the voltage, I just want to measure the accumulated current, however small.  I have managed to collect current into a capacitor as large as 1uf, without any amp, within a few seconds, and measure the voltage across the capacitor.  Does the op-amp buffer improve the measuring stability or accuracy?

Comment: @CaptainCodeman Please just look up what an op-amp voltage follower circuit does. I know it has amplifier in the name, but amplifier doesn't necessarily mean what you think it means. I also said op-amp BUFFER (or voltage follower) circuit.

Answer (score 3):

To measure the light intensity using photodiode, you'd use a [transimpedance amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transimpedance_amplifier). There're many sources of the principle circuit of such transimpedance amplifiers.

Here's the practical schematics diagram of the transimpedance amplifer I designed. It is tested in the field with optical instruments of high accuracy. It worked as designed in all range 0.1 ~ 10,000 lx.

In this circuit, I used high-resolution ADC, Thus, sampling speed is not so high. If you need higher speed sampling, you can use 8-bit or 10-bit like faster ADCs.
And you can switch the ADC by software instead of using two capacitors in your circuit.

"Input" is the cable from photodiode sensor head.
As the photodiode current is very small, this frontend circuit is sensitive to external noises. So, when designing the circuit, need to be careful. I used a single-pointed ground here and it worked fine.

To increase dynamic range, you'd change the feedback resistor values. Though I used PGA here, you can just use jumper or switch if you need a simpler circuit.

[image]

Comment: As I understand the amplifier increases the output voltage signal, but is that necessary if we're just collecting current in a capacitor?

Comment: light current of a photodiode is pA ~ uA range. You'll find difficulties if you're going to charge the capacitors directly using such small current.

Comment: I charged a 1uf cap with just the photodiode current

Comment: As long as you don't need accurate result, that might be.

Comment: Why does it become more accurate if you amplify the signal?  Can you not just get the same result from a smaller charge in a smaller cap?

Comment: With an ideal capacitor and ideal ADC, you'll get the result. If real-world situation is so, there'll be no need of any analog frontend amplifiers.

Comment: There will be leakage currents of your gate MOSFETs, ADC inputs, discharge trigger circuits, and capacitor itself. In pA or nA range, such leakage currents cannot be neglected.